# Добавление нескольких переменных POST при отправке формы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма, в ней разные кнопки. По нажатию кнопки submit создается одна переменная, имя и значение берутся из атрибутов кнопки. Есть потребность отправлять несколько переменных при нажати кнопки. Как это сделать?

Посмотрел похожие темы на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993834/adding-post-parameters-before-submit и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530635/jquery-add-additional-parameters-on-submit-not-ajax

Там были решения, но мне хочется сделать не код встраиваемый в страницу, а в функцию.
Прикинул следующий код кнопки:

```
<button type="button" onclick="addPOSTvar([ ['name1' , 'value1'] , ['name2' , 'value2'], ['name3','value3'] ])">Кнопка для 3 переменных</button>
```

и код javascript:

```
function addPOSTvar( params ) {  
var form = $(this).closest('form');   
form.append($.map(params, function (param) {
    return   $('<input>', {
        type: 'hidden',
        name: param[0],
        value: param[1]
    })
}));  
form.submit();
```

Код получился нерабочий, что нужно подкорректировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, что заметил - у вас контекст функции неверный ... п.э. не определяется элемент формы ...

```
<button type="button" onclick="addPOSTvar(this, [ ['name1' , 'value1'] , ['name2' , 'value2'], ['name3','value3'] ])">Кнопка для 3 переменных</button>
```

js:

```
function addPOSTvar(context, params ) {  
var form = $(context).closest('form');   
form.append($.map(params, function (param) {
    return   $('<input>', {
        type: 'hidden',
        name: param[0],
        value: param[1]
    })
}));  
form.submit();
}
```